# Which version of GetAttributeValue of the 'HTML Agility Pack' is used when calling from PowerShell with the second parameter $null?

Tags: c#, powershell, polymorphism, html-agility-pack, generic-method

I am writing a PowerShell script to work in Windows 10. I am using the 'HTML Agility Pack' library version 1.11.43.

In this library, [there is](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/master/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared/HtmlNode.cs) a `GetAttributeValue` method for HTML element nodes in four versions:

1. `public string GetAttributeValue(string name, string def)`
2. `public int GetAttributeValue(string name, int def)`
3. `public bool GetAttributeValue(string name, bool def)`
4. `public T GetAttributeValue<T>(string name, T def)`

I have written a test script for these methods on PowerShell:

```powershell
$libPath = "HtmlAgilityPack.1.11.43\lib\netstandard2.0\HtmlAgilityPack.dll"
Add-Type -Path $libPath
$dom = New-Object -TypeName "HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument"
$dom.Load("test.html", [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)

foreach ($node in $dom.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes()) {
    if ("#text" -ne $node.Name) {
        $node.OuterHTML
        "    " + $node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
        "    " + $node.GetAttributeValue("class", 0)
        "    " + $node.GetAttributeValue("class", $true)
        "    " + $node.GetAttributeValue("class", $false)
        "    " + $node.GetAttributeValue("class", $null)
    }
}
```

File 'test.html':

```html
<p class="true"></p>
<p class="false"></p>
<p></p>
<p class="any other text"></p>
```

Test script execution result:

```
<p class="true"></p>
    true
    0
    True
    True
    True
<p class="false"></p>
    false
    0
    False
    False
    False
<p></p>

    0
    True
    False
    False
<p class="any other text"></p>
    any other text
    0
    True
    False
    False
```

I know that to get the attribute value of an HTML element, you can also use the expression `$node.Attributes["class"]`. I also understand what polymorphism and method overloading are.  I also know what a generic method is. I don't need to explain that.

I have three questions:

1. When called `$node.GetAttributeValue("class", $null)` from a PowerShell script, which of the four variants of the `GetAttributeValue` method works?
2. I think the fourth option works (generic method). Then why does a call with the second parameter `$null` work exactly the same as a call with the second parameter `$false`?
3. In the C# source code, the fourth option requires the following condition to work

```
#if !(METRO || NETSTANDARD1_3 || NETSTANDARD1_6)
```

I tried the library versions for `NETSTANDARD1_6` and for `NETSTANDARD2_0`. The test script works the same way. But with `NETSTANDARD1_6` the fourth option should be unavailable, right? Then when `NETSTANDARD1_6` then which version of the method `GetAttributeValue` works with the second parameter `$null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

To achieve what you unsuccessfully attempted with 
`$node.GetAttributeValue("class", $null)`, i.e., to return the attribute value as a `[string]` and default to `$null` if there is none, use:

```bash
$node.GetAttributeValue("class", [string] [NullString]::Value)
```

<sup>`[string] $null` works too, but makes `""` (the empty string) rather than `$null` the default value.</sup>

---

While the overload resolution that you're seeing is surprising, you can **resolve ambiguity during PowerShell's method overload resolution with *casts***:

```bash
$dom = [HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument]::new()
$dom.LoadHtml(@'
<p class="true"></p>
<p class=42></p>
<p></p>
<p class="any other text"></p>
'@)

$nodes = $dom.DocumentNode.SelectNodes('p')

# Note the use of explicit casts (e.g., [string]) to guide overload resolution.
$nodes[0].GetAttributeValue('class', [bool] $false)
$nodes[1].GetAttributeValue('class', [int] 0)
$nodes[2].GetAttributeValue('class', [string] 'default')
$nodes[3].GetAttributeValue('class', [string] [NullString]::Value)
```

Output:

```bash
True
42
default
any other text
```

Alternatively, in ***PowerShell (Core) 7.3+***<sup>[1]</sup>, you can now **call *generic* methods with explicit type arguments**:

```bash
# PS 7.3+
# Note the generic type argument directly after the method  name.
# Calls the one and only generic overload, with various types substituted for T:
#   public T GetAttributeValue<T>(string name, T def)
# Note how the 2nd argument doesn't need a cast anymore.
$nodes[0].GetAttributeValue[bool]('class',  $false)
$nodes[1].GetAttributeValue[int]('class', 0)
$nodes[2].GetAttributeValue[string]('class', 'default')
$nodes[3].GetAttributeValue[string]('class', [NullString]::Value)
```

Note:

- When you pass `$null` to a `[string]` typed parameter (both in cmdlets and .NET methods), PowerShell actually converts it quietly to `""` (the empty string). `[NullString]::Value` tell's PowerShell to pass a true `null` instead, and is mostly needed for calling .NET methods where a behavioral distinction can result from passing `null` vs. `""`.
- Therefore, if you were to call `$nodes[3].GetAttributeValue('class', [string] $null)` or, in PS 7.3+, `$nodes[3].GetAttributeValue[string]('class', $null)`, you'd get `""`  (empty string) as the default value if attribute `class` doesn't exist.
- By contrast, `[NullString]::Value`, as used in the commands above, causes a true `$null` value to be returned if the attribute doesn't exist; you can test for that with `$null -eq ...`.

---

As for **your questions**:

On a general note, PowerShell's overload resolution is complex, and for the ultimate source of truth you'll have to consult the [source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell). The following is based on the de-facto behavior as of PowerShell 7.2.6 and musings about logic that *could* be applied.

> When calling `$node.GetAttributeValue("class", $null)` from a PowerShell script, which of the four variants of the GetAttributeValue method works?

In practice, the `public bool GetAttributeValue(string name, bool def)` overload is chosen; why it, specifically, is chosen among the available overloads is ultimately immaterial, because the fundamental problem is that **to PowerShell, `$null` provides *insufficient information* as to the type it may be a stand-in for**, so it **cannot generally be expected to select a specific overload** (for the latter, you need a *cast*, as shown at the top):

- In *C#* passing `null` to the second parameter in a non-generic call unambiguously implies the overload with the `string`-typed `def` parameter, because among the non-generic overloads, `string` as the type of the `def` parameter is the only *.NET reference type*, and therefore the only type that can directly accept a `null` argument.
- This is *not* true in **PowerShell**, which has **much more flexible, *implicit* type-conversion rules**: from PowerShell's perspective, `$null` can bind to *any* of the types among the `def` parameters, because it allows `$null` to be converted to those types; specifically, `[bool] $null` yields `$false`, `[int] $null` yields `0`, and - perhaps surprisingly, as discussed above - `[string] $null` yields `""` (the empty string).

  - Thus, PowerShell is justified in selecting *any one* of the non-generic overloads in this case, and which one it chooses should be considered an *implementation detail*.

However, curiously, even using `[NullString]::Value` doesn't make a difference, even though PowerShell *should* know that this special value represents a `$null` value for a `string` parameter - see [GitHub issue #18072](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18072)

---

> I think the fourth option works (generic method). Then why does a call with the second parameter $null work exactly the same as a call with the second parameter $false?

With the generic invocation syntax available in v7.3+, the generic overload definitely works - and a `$null` as the default-value argument is converted to the type specified as the type argument (assuming PowerShell allows such a conversion; it wouldn't work with `[datetime]`, for instance, because `[datetime] $null` causes an error).

Even with the non-generic syntax, PowerShell *does* select the generic overload *by inference*, as the following example shows, but only when you pass an actual object rather than `$null`:

```bash
# Try to retrieve a non-existent attribute and provide a [double]
# default value.
# The fact that a [double] instance is returned implies that the
# generic overload was chosen.
#  -> 'System.Double'
$nodes[0].GetAttributeValue('nosuch', [double] $null).GetType().FullName
```

> In the C# source code, the fourth option requires the following condition to work [...]

When you pass `$null`, the generic overload is *not* considered - and cannot be, in the absence of type information - so this doesn't make a difference.

---

<sup>[1] As of this writing, v7.3 hasn't been released yet, but *preview* versions are available - see [the repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).</sup>

Comment: I marked your answer as an answer to my question because it is very useful and really answers my questions. But what is happening is not completely clear to me. For `$null`, the generic method doesn't work at all? I realized that a variant of the method with the `bool` type is being selected. But you don't know the reason for this?

Comment: I'm glad to hear the answer is useful, @IlyaChalov. Please see my update, which explains why `$null` doesn't work in more detail. In short: in PowerShell - unlike in C# - it is _ambiguous_, due to the implicit type conversions PowerShell generally performs. Using an explicit cast (`[string] $null`) is the solution, though, as noted, for separate reasons that actually makes `""`, not `$null`, the default value. Thus, `[string] [NullString]::Value` is the equivalent of passing `null` in C#.